# Jquery find subelement from $(this)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, this

I have a table in in which every row contains a form. see below

```
<table>
<tr><th>Fee Type</th><th>Amount</th><th>% Discount</th><th>Discounted Amount</th><th>Payable to</th><th>Remove</th></tr>    
<tr>
   <form>
         <td></td>
         <td class="cost"></td>
         <td> <input /> </td>
         <td class="discount"></td>
         <td></td>
   </form>
<tr>
</table>
```

Now my intention is to have a global save button which will loop through each form and perform an ajax post. see below

```
    function saveEditedFees(){
        $("#savefeechanges").click(function(){
            $("#feestable form").each(function(){
                alert( $(this).attr('id') );
            });
        });
    }
```

My problem is accessing values for the "td" using the $(this) for the elements with class **"cost"** and **"discount"**
I tried

```
alert( $(this).find("td").eq(2).html() );
alert($(this).siblings('.cost').text());
alert($("td .cost" ,this).text());
```

Basically, I am trying to test if the value contained in the `<td class="cost">` is equal to the `<td class="discount">` , this way i will selectively do an ajax post.

Please help.

Comment: Maybe? $(this).find('.cost').text()

Comment: No, been there tried that before as well. Didn't work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Invalid markup.

You have a `<form>` as a child of `<tr>`.

In Chrome, the HTML is rendered as:

```
<tr>
   <form></form>
         <td></td>
         <td class="cost"></td>
         <td> <input> </td>
         <td class="discount"></td>
         <td></td>
</tr>
```

As you can see, the `<form>` no longer has any content.

And remember that `.eq()` takes a zero-based index, so it should be:

```
$(this).find("td").eq(1)
```

...to get the `.cost` element.

Comment: I agree. `<form>` isn't going to fit in that context. It would be better to have one giant `<form>` around the table, and then loop over the `<tr>` elements.

Comment: @Binaryrespawn: Either have an individual table in each form, or have a single form that encompasses the entire table. Depends on your needs.

Comment: I just realised that i may not even need a form, i can simply use jquery post() and send accross my data manually as its just two fields.

Comment: @Binaryrespawn: True, though it will only work if JavaScript is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to have a space in your line that says:

```
alert($("td .cost" ,this).text());
```

It should be

```
alert($("td.cost", this).text());
```

Keep in mind that the context of `this` is going to mean that `this` refers to the form element, so `siblings()` won't work. I think you're on the right track with `$("td.cost", this)` using either `.html()` or `.text()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).closest('form').find('.cost');
```

This is similar to another question I answered where I explained [traversal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260845/how-to-select-an-image-into-an-anchor-to-apply-jquery-events/8260913#8260913).

However, you should refactor your html before proceeding, as a TR element should only contain TDs or THs. If you feel that you need to nest a table inside of another table for layout purposes then so-be-it. I would recommend divs in this case, but breaking table conventions is sure to lead to tears down the roa.